# Volume of a Vase (with Calculus)

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, definite-integrals, volume

I'm having trouble calculating the volume of a vase. Moreover, i've found the equation and found the volume through one method - in which i divided the vase into 100 cylinders. I summed the 100 volumes of the 100 cylinders and ended with 1509.192376cm^3.

I'm asking for help to find the volume of the vase using calculus as I need to validate whether my cylindrical method is accurate is works.In regards to calculus, i was thinking of using integration but can't seem to put my head around it...

The equation:
Y = 0.00007202x^6 - 0.00298409x^5 + 0.04474982x^4 - 0.28787259x^3 + 0.68195292x^2 - 0.10780426x + 6.03715171

For integration: a = 0, b = 12.

[the graph looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naQnR.png)

**I have called the function a vase, as i am suppose to imagine that the function would be flipped onto the other side as a reflection. Also, i know it still wouldnt actually represent a vase, but it kinda does i guess?

I was not given an equation for the function, I was instead given x and y co-ordinates (see below) in which I used in excel to create a graphical representation. 
x   y
0   6
1   6.5
2   6.75
3   7
4   6.75
5   6.5
6   6
7   5.5
8   5.75
9   6.25
10  6.5
11  6.25
12  6

Additionally, I was instructed to choose a polynomial 6 trendline as it had the best r^2 value.

Comment: What do your $x$ and $y$ represent?  What is their connection to the shape of the vase?

Comment: You have not described a vase yet. The graph of a polynomial of degree six is a planar object, and doesn't make a vase. Also, it is a good idea to [study our collected hints on asking an acceptable question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: That graph still doesn't look like a vase. It is a planar region. Care to explain what **the vase** looks like

Comment: Hi, I should have added that this question is about a rotation of a line along the x-axis. Imagine the graph is being identically reflected.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume of a curve rotated about the $x$-axis is well known through variuos methods (e.g., disc and Pappus's $2^{nd}$ Centroid theorem) and is given by

$$V=\pi \int y^2~dx$$

In your case we find

$$V=\pi \int_0^{12} y^2~dx\approx 1509.42$$

Comment: Hi,Thanks for this! Just a question, did you use the equation of 0.00007202x^6 - 0.00298409x^5 + 0.04474982x^4 - 0.28787259x^3 + 0.68195292x^2 - 0.10780426x + 6.03715171 as 'y'?

Comment: You're welcome. I just copied the equation in the question.